# how to predict binary outcome with categorical and continuous features using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, r, machine-learning

I need advice choosing a model and machine learning algorithm for a classification problem.

I'm trying to predict a binary outcome for a subject. I have 500,000 records in my data set and 20 continuous and categorical features. Each subject has 10--20 records. The data is labeled with its outcome.

So far I'm thinking logistic regression model and kernel approximation, based on the cheat-sheet [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/).

I am unsure where to start when implementing this in either R or Python.

Thanks!

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/documentation.html I'm not sure what else to tell you

Comment: Solving machine learning problems almost always requires iteration. Start by looking at your data and visualizing it, so that you have some intuition about its characteristics. After this, build a quick and dirty model using cross validation. This will give you a rudimentary baseline to start with. You probably should try to understand which features are most predictive, using logistic regression (examining R squared), or perhaps decision trees to get a high-level sense of which variables are most important and which are redundant. This will help you avoid multicollinearity. Good luck.

Comment: I'm not asking what the parameters of the model should be, nor am I asking for advice on how to validate/calibrate a machine learning algorithm, nor is it helpful to be pointed to the documentation for a specific software implementation of a set of algorithms. I'm asking about model class and appropriate algorithm for the structure of the data I have presented, and if it is trivial, suitable packages to perform this. Thank you for your comments and answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing an algorithm and optimizing the parameter is a difficult task in any data mining project. Because it must customized for your data and problem. Try different algorithm like SVM,Random Forest, Logistic Regression, KNN and... and test Cross Validation for each of them and then compare them.
You can use [GridSearch in sickit learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html) to try different parameters and optimize the parameters for each algorithm. also try [this project](https://github.com/rsteca/sklearn-deap)
witch test a range of parameters with genetic algorithm

Answer (score 0):

### Features

If your categorical features don't have too many possible different values, you might want to have a look at [`sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

### Model choice

The choice of "the best" model depends mainly on the amount of available training data and the simplicity of the decision boundary you expect to get.

You can try dimensionality reduction to 2 or 3 dimensions. Then you can visualize your data and see if there is a nice decision boundary.

With 500,000 training examples you can think about using a neural network. I can recommend [Keras](https://keras.io/) for beginners and [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) for people who know how neural networks work.

You should also know that there are [Ensemble methods](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html).

A nice cheat sheet what to use is on [in the sklearn tutorial](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/) you already found:

[image]
<sub>(source: [scikit-learn.org](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/_static/ml_map.png))</sub>

Just try it, compare different results. Without more information it is not possible to give you better advice.